# Homebrew failed on installation, but now won't uninstall

Tags: homebrew

I used the following command to install Homebrew:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Which then returns this as an error:

```
It appears Homebrew is already installed. If your intent is to reinstall you should do the following before running this installer again:
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"
```

When I run that command in terminal, I simply get "Failed to locate Homebrew!"

Comment: What is the output of `which brew` and can you execute `brew doctor`?

Comment: When I try `which brew`, it doesn't output anything. `brew doctor` outputs `brew: command not found`.

Comment: `ls -la /usr/local`?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue on mac OS. A lot of answers on here advised me to remove /usr/local/.git but this did not exist. My solution was as follows:

I navigated to:

```
/usr/local/Homebrew/bin
```

And ran:

```
./brew doctor
```

It warned me Homebrews bin was not found and advised me to add it to my .bash_profile like so:

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/Homebrew/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

After this I started a new session and I was back brewing

Answer (score 3):

I was at same situation and do this:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/.git
chown <your_username> /usr/local
```

After that, I can install Homebrew.

Comment: Nope, didn't work. I get:      `fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Operation timed out
Failed during: git fetch origin master:refs/remotes/origin/master -n --depth=1`

Comment: But that is a different problem. Are you accusing Intertet throw a proxy?